# How to set multi interval in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a scenario about using RxJava with interval operator. In fact, I can set interval for Job A. Like that

```
Observable
    .interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map(new Func1<Long, List<Bean>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Bean> call(Long pLong) {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<List<Bean>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<Bean> pO) {
            if (pO.size() > 0) setData(pO);
        }
    });
```

But I tried to set interval for Job A, Job B, Job C but they have different interval between them.

Job A, Job B, Job C (30 seconds)
Job A -> 5 seconds -> Job B -> 10 seconds -> Job C

```
Observable
    .interval(0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Long> call(Long pLong) {
            //Job A
            return Observable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Long> call(Long pLong) {
            //Job B
            return Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Long pO) {
            //Job C
            if (pO.size() > 0) setData(pO);
        }
    });
```

I tried to use something like this but no luck. I am new to Rx, appreciate any comment about it.

Comment: it's entirely clear, are you trying to do series of jobs (A,B,C) every 30 sec, where each job has delay between each other?

Answer (score 1):

.interval() generates sequence of events, try using .timer() for triggering another job, or .interval().take(1). You will start job B (10 seconds) every 5 seconds (overlapping intervals?)